# Which scons command is good for compiling my godot native script project?

Tags: c++, syntax-error, scons, godot

I want to use C++ script for my Godot project so I am trying to build the godot-cpp repository with scons.

[image]
[image]

Which command do I have to use?

Comment: Does `include/godot_cpp/core/memory.hpp` `#include <type_traits>` and are you compiling in C++17 (or later) mode?

Comment: Did you follow all the directions on godot's website? https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/compiling_for_windows.html

Comment: Yes it is C++17

Comment: Yes include/godot_cpp/core/memory.hpp #include <type_traits>

Comment: Yes it is C++17